# Bootstrap Select with search not working as expected with AngularJS MVC partial view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, select, partial-views

Bootstrap select with data-live-search working fine with normal views but not working as expected with partial view which are rendered within the main view (`Index.cshtml`)

```
Bootstrap select with Normal View        Bootstrap select with Partial View
```

[image: Bootstrap select with Normal View][image: Bootstrap select with Partial View]

I have Index page wherein all the jQuery files are included at the bottom of the page and partial views are rendered based on menu selection. I'm using nested ui-router.

```
    <div class="page-container">
      <div class="page-content">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
      </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-loader.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-kendo.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js'></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/scrolltotop/scrolltopcontrol.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/rickshaw/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-file-input.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/actions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/demo_dashboard.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we need to create a directive for this, something like below and then call it in our html form by using attribute select-picker

```js
  .directive('selectPicker', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ["?ngModel", "?ngCollection"],
            priority: 10,
            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                tElement.selectpicker($parse(tAttrs.selectpicker)());
                tElement.selectpicker('refresh');
                return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    if (!ngModel) return;

                    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                        scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                            if (!attrs.ngOptions || /track by/.test(attrs.ngOptions)) 
                                element.val(newVal);
                                element.selectpicker('refresh');
                        });
                    });

                    ngModel.$render = function() {
                        element.selectpicker("val", ngModel.$viewValue || "");
                    };

                    ngModel.$viewValue = element.val();
                };
            }
            
        };
    }])
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 control-label">Bank Short Name</label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control with-search" select-picker data-live-search="true" title="Select Bank" 
 ng-model="selectedMasterBank"
 ng-options="b as b.shortName for b in masterbanks"
 ng-change="onChangeSelectedMasterBank(selectedMasterBank)">
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working... but there is some problem. On page load blank options are shown in select, but when clicked on any blank option it shows all the options with correct data.

Comment: Make sure that when you load the form or screen, you set or trigger the corresponding view model of the select option. In my example above, the view model of select option is selectedMasterBank. I set this value in my controller like this: $scope.masterbanks = response.data; $scope.selectedMasterBank = $scope.masterbanks[0]; The main idea is to make sure you initiate or trigger selectedMasterBank with a value. Since it will be caught by scope.$watch's part of the directive.